# Setting domain name for ip address on pi (Apache, DHCP)

Tags: apache, server, raspberry-pi, dhcp

I set up my pi to broadcast it's own "wifi" and I have an Apache server running on it.

I used this tutorial https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point

I can currently connect to the network that the pi is broadcasting and go to the ip of the server on my phone and it brings up the webpage, but I want to be able to type in "mydomain.net" and have it bring me to the webpage. Can anyone help me with this or suggest anything?

I want anyone that wants to connect to this local wifi (not worldwide) to be able to enter the website so changing everyone's host file is not going to happen.

Comment: You just need to register your domain name and point DNS to your server's IP. You did buy a domain name right?

Comment: @takendarkk How would you point the DNS to the IP? I have looked in etc/apache2/apache2.conf and /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

Answer (score 1):

you can modify `/etc/hosts` file on your local machine to point the custom domain name to the IP address of the environment you want to test. The `/etc/hosts` file contains a mapping of IP addresses to URLs.

Your browser uses entries in the `/etc/hosts` file to override the IP-address-to-URL mapping returned by a DNS server.

This is only useful for testing DNS (domain name system) changes and the SSL configuration before making a website live.

Comment: I may have not worded it correctly, but I want anyone who is near the pi to be able to use "myexample.com" so with your suggestion, I'd have to go into everybody's host file and change it.